# How many combinations of groups are there possible in a set of 50 students with 10 groups of 5?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Say you have $50$ students in a class. You want to divide them into $10$ groups of $5$. How many different ways can you do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First method: Sort people into ten *labeled* groups and then recognize that you have overcounted.  There are $\binom{50}{5,5,\dots,5}=\binom{50}{5}\binom{45}{5}\binom{40}{5}\cdots\binom{10}{5}=\frac{50!}{(5!)^{10}}$ ways that you can do this.  Now, we recognize that each outcome we actually counted $10!$ different times.  Dividing by $10!$ corrects this mistake giving us a final total of:

$$\frac{50!}{(5!)^{10}}\cdot\frac{1}{10!}$$

Second method: As "division by symmetry" arguments can make people nervous, we can instead approach more carefully to avoid overcounting.  As we have 50 distinct people, there must be some obvious way that we can label them and arrange them.  I will continue based on ordering the people by height, but you could choose a different ordering if you choose.

Among the 50 people, there must be someone who is shortest.  We first pick who the four other people in the shortest person's group is.  This can be accomplished in $\binom{49}{4}$ ways.  We then remove all of these four people along with the original shortest person from the pool of available people to be placed in groups later.

Next, among the 45 remaining people, there must be someone who is shortest.  We pick the four other people in the shortest remaining person's group.  This can be accomplished in $\binom{44}{4}$ ways.  Continue as before removing these people from the available pool.

Repeat this process until everyone has been assigned a group.  This gives a final total number of ways as:

$$\binom{49}{4}\binom{44}{4}\cdots \binom{14}{4}\binom{9}{4}$$

One can check that this answer is equal to the previous answer.

Comment: Perhaps the question was changed.  It now says $10$ groups of $5$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I saw the comment above, easily fixed, but it does make plugging into a calculator more difficult to verify

Answer (score 2):

The first $5$ students can be chosen in $\binom{50}{5}$ ways.

The next $5$ in $\binom{45}{5}$ ways.

The next $5$ in $\binom{40}{5}$ ways.

...

The next $5$ in $\binom{10}{5}$ ways.

The last $5$ can only be chosen in $1$ way.

These $10$ groups of $5$ could have been chosen in $10!$ ways 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{10!} \binom{50}{5}\binom{45}{5}\binom{40}{5}\cdots\binom{10}{5}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Perhaps the question was changed.  It now says $10$ groups of $5$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I think I got the $5$ & $10$ the wrong way around to start with ? Anyway thank you for your help. $ \ddot \smile$

Answer (score 0):

The ans varies for *labelled* groups, (i.e. distinguishable, say, as $A,B,C, ...$) and *unlabelled* ones.

For *labelled* groups, the answer is $\binom{50}5\binom{45}5\binom{40}5 .... \binom55$,

or more succinctly, using the multinomial coefficient, $\binom{50}{5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5}$ equivalent to $\frac{50!}{5!5!5!5!5!5!5!5!5!5!}$

For *unlabelled* groups, you'd obviously need to divide the above by $10!$,
as you can't distinguish one group from another.